# https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken is returning 400 error only for one user

Tags: linkedin-api

This issue is only happening with one specific user. I am unable to reproduce an issue I am seeing in my error logs. I tried this a number of times with several people trying to reproduce this.

I see this error message from LinkedIn:

missing required parameters, includes an invalid parameter value, parameter more than once. : Unable to retrieve access token : appId or redirect uri does not match authorization code or authorization code expired

Any ideas why this user would be any different?